# Calling readAllBytes on an InputStream of a process returns empty byte array

Tags: java

I'm trying to get the terminal width by executing `tput cols` command and parse the output.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tput cols");
        String output = new String(p.getInputStream().readAllBytes());
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

But it outputs empty string.
However, if I executes it in the terminal I can see the output.

Comment: Did you check "getErrorStream"? Did you check the process exit code?

Comment: For the record, this works fine for me. How are you running it? If I run it from a terminal then I get the same value back that I get from just running `tput cols` if you run it from something that doesn't provide a terminal you might not get the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the command to terminate. When you read the output of the `tput` command, it has not yet terminated and therefore there is not yet any output.

I prefer using class `ProcessBuilder` rather than class `Runtime`.

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class PrcBldTs {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("tput", "cols");
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            int result = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("result = " + result);
        }
        catch (Exception x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don’t think this is correct.  readAllBytes() will keep reading from the process until the process is finished.  But I do agree that ProcessBuilder is the better choice, especially if one calls `redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT)` on it so errors are not hidden.